# lshistory command does not give the logs of subfolders?

Tags: java, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am trying to get the changes in the files in a particular folder which have subfolders also

example

folder a3

```
- folder a3
    - App.java
    - folder com
        -folder akshay
           - folder jain
                - Person.java
```

then i have made some changes in the App.java and Person.java and apply the command on a3

> cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n,%c" |findstr "US-100"

but in the output of command it is only showing the App.java have  changed in particular revision but not about the Person.java because it is in subfolders

Anyone have any idea..to get the logs of subfolders file also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [`cleartool lshistory`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-25) command, you do have the option `-recurse`:

```
-r/ecurse
```

> Processes the entire subtree below any directory element encountered.
>   VOB symbolic links are not traversed during the recursive descent.
>   Note: This option is mutually exclusive with –last.

so this might have more chance to pick-up changes in `Person.java`:

```
cleartool lshistory -r -fmt "%n,%c" |findstr "US-100"
```